# What Built-in Form Validation Does App Engine/Django Have?

Tags: django, validation, google-app-engine

I'm writing an app using App Engine and Django.  What Built-in Form Validation Does App Engine/Django Have?  For example how can I verify that the user actually entered an integer and not a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Engine bundles Django 0.96, which includes the 'newforms' form validation library. You can find documentation on that [here](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/newforms/). There's also [an article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html) on the App Engine site that details how to integrate Django's forms library with App Engine models.

Answer (score 1):

Django (as of 1.0) has a fairly detailed data validation framework for form fields. It's documented [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)

Answer (score -1):

Django 0.96 which is included in AppEngine API uses *oldforms* (manipulators) library. The validation was performed in somewhat more complicated way. The [documentation is available](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/forms/), though not so easily accessible.

Comment: Actually, Django 0.96 supports newforms.

Comment: Oh, yes, in a very limited form.